# redirect to an error page in Liferay from Autologin

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to generate an error page for specific failure from **AutoLogin class** and redirect to same.

```
request.setAttribute(AutoLogin.AUTO_LOGIN_REDIRECT, internalErrorPage);
```

what I want to know how can I create **internalErrorPage jsp page** in **Liferay** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a portlet and redirect to the URL you create JSP in the portlet:

```
request.setAttribute(AutoLogin.AUTO_LOGIN_REDIRECT, "http://www.yourhost.com/somerrorpage.html");
return null;
```

[AutoLogin Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606682/autologin-firing-in-liferay-from-a-redirection)

Regards! :)

Comment: thanks, But I do not understand your answer. I just need to create a JSP or html page and call from redirect. So i need to know where i create this jsp page or html page, and how do i call(path).